# Change process name for Windows Task Manager

Tags: c#, process, taskmanager

I have an C#/.NET application that behaves similarly to svchost--we use it to start our services, each of which resides in a separate DLL. When looking in the Task Manager, all of these show up with the same name--the name of the executable process that started them.

We would like to make each of these be named uniquely. Is there an API call that can be made to set the process name dynamically--i.e. to a string that is read from a configuration file?

I've read the other similar topics, but they haven't helped. A response to Question #14711100 suggested using symlinks, to which the response was that doesn't work. That question was also about killing and starting, so the answers were geared toward that problem.

Others mentioned setting the window title bar text or the process name of the executable. Those don't apply here because there is no window title bar, and the same executable is used to launch different processes.

Question #1402824 seems to be the closest. Is there any libc implementation available under Windows that would work?

If this can't be done, then are there any ways to somehow fake it? Our main goal is to be able to distinguish which process is which in Task Manager and similar process lists.

If we could even use the PID to get at the full command line, that would probably help.

As a last resort, if I set up some sort of supervisor that copies the EXE to a new name before launching, what are the implications that I should consider? Would I need to worry about anything duplicated in memory? Anything shared in memory? Anyone stomping on anyone's data, files, etc? An answer to Question #1402824 mentioned the same context. What do we need to know about that?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I learned that I could get the process information using the wmic tool:

```
wmic service where (pathname like "%%svchostOrWhatever.exe%%" and state="Running") get DisplayName,Name,PathName,ProcessId,StartMode
```

This might end up being what we have to live with if we can't change the image name. Regarding that, I did find this VB 6.0 project by Billy Conner:

http://www.planetsourcecode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=66443&lngWId=1

I understand things have changed a lot since 2006, but I thought it's worth a try. (FYI I'm on Windows 7.)

It looks like it's basically using SendMessage to send a LVM_SETITEMTEXT message with the desired process name. I translated the calls to C# using P/Invoke, but it doesn't appear to work.

If I understand the API correctly, SendMessage will return true (nonzero) for LVM_SETITEMTEXT if it succeeded and false (zero) if failed, and then I can find out more information as usual using the managed version of GetLastError.

When I ran this in my svchost equivalent, SendMessage() returned zero. I called Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() and got back 1400, which looks like I'm getting ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE. Ok, maybe I can't run this on a Windows service since it doesn't have a window.

Then, I tried it in a dummy WPF application. This time, I still got a 0 back from SendMessage(), but GetLastWin32Error is also returning zero.

The dummy application has an App.xaml and a MainWindow.xaml. I placed the following call at the end of my MainWindow constructor in the code behind:

```
     IntPtr handle = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;
     SetItemText(handle, "Gobbledygook.exe", 0);
```

Here is the definition of SetItemText as taken and translated from Connor's project:

```
  public static void SetItemText(IntPtr handle,
                                 string desiredImageName,
                                 long index,
                                 long subIndex = 0)
  {
     // TODO: Check return values for errors...
     desiredImageName = string.Format("{0}\0", desiredImageName); // TODO: Is the nul character required?
     byte[] memStorage = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(desiredImageName);
     long size = memStorage.Length;

     // allocate some shared memory for our string
     IntPtr sharedProcMemString = VirtualAllocEx(handle,
                                               IntPtr.Zero,
                                               (uint)size,
                                               AllocationType.Reserve | AllocationType.Commit,
                                               MemoryProtection.ReadWrite);

     // setup some info
     LVITEM lvi = new LVITEM()
     {
        iItem = (int)index,
        iSubItem = (int)subIndex,
        cchTextMax = (int)size,
        pszText = sharedProcMemString // store our string handle
     };

     // allocate some shared memory for our Struct
     IntPtr sharedProcMem = VirtualAllocEx(handle,
                                         IntPtr.Zero,
                                         (uint)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(lvi),
                                         AllocationType.Reserve | AllocationType.Commit,
                                         MemoryProtection.ReadWrite);

     // write to memory
     WriteProcessMemory(handle, sharedProcMemString, memStorage);
     WriteProcessMemory(handle, sharedProcMem, GetBytes(lvi));

     // get the text
     IntPtr result = SendMessage(handle, LVM_SETITEMTEXTA, (IntPtr)index, sharedProcMem);

     if ((int)result == 0) // false, i.e. error
     {
        int errorCode = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        // TODO: do something with errorCode - e.g. log it?
     }

     // clean up
     VirtualFreeEx(handle, sharedProcMem, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(lvi), AllocationType.Release);
     VirtualFreeEx(handle, sharedProcMemString, (int)size, AllocationType.Release);
  }
```

Here are some supporting routines:

```
  private static byte[] GetBytes(LVITEM str)
  {
     int size = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(str);
     byte[] arr = new byte[size];
     IntPtr ptr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

     System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(str, ptr, true);
     System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);
     System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

     return arr;
  }

  public static void WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr handle, IntPtr writeAddress, byte[] buffer)
  {
     int bytesWritten;
     WriteProcessMemory(handle, writeAddress, buffer, (uint)buffer.Length, out bytesWritten);
  }
```

Here are the necessary P/Invoke declarations:

```
  private const int LVM_FIRST = 0x1000;
  private const int LVM_GETITEMCOUNT = LVM_FIRST + 4;
  private const int LVM_GETITEM = LVM_FIRST + 75;
  private const int LVIF_TEXT = 0x0001;
  private const int LVM_SETITEMTEXTA = (LVM_FIRST + 46);

  [Flags]
  public enum AllocationType
  {
     Commit = 0x1000,
     Reserve = 0x2000,
     Decommit = 0x4000,
     Release = 0x8000,
     Reset = 0x80000,
     Physical = 0x400000,
     TopDown = 0x100000,
     WriteWatch = 0x200000,
     LargePages = 0x20000000
  }

  [Flags]
  public enum MemoryProtection
  {
     Execute = 0x10,
     ExecuteRead = 0x20,
     ExecuteReadWrite = 0x40,
     ExecuteWriteCopy = 0x80,
     NoAccess = 0x01,
     ReadOnly = 0x02,
     ReadWrite = 0x04,
     WriteCopy = 0x08,
     GuardModifierflag = 0x100,
     NoCacheModifierflag = 0x200,
     WriteCombineModifierflag = 0x400
  }

  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  private struct LVITEM
  {
     public uint mask;
     public int iItem;
     public int iSubItem;
     public uint state;
     public uint stateMask;
     public IntPtr pszText;
     public int cchTextMax;
     public int iImage;
     public IntPtr lParam;
  }

  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
  private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd,
                                           int Msg,
                                           IntPtr wParam,
                                           IntPtr lParam);

  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
  private static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess,
                                              IntPtr lpAddress,
                                              uint dwSize,
                                              AllocationType flAllocationType,
                                              MemoryProtection flProtect);

  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
  private static extern bool VirtualFreeEx(IntPtr hProcess,
                                           IntPtr lpAddress,
                                           int dwSize,
                                           AllocationType dwFreeType);

  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  private static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess,
                                        IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
                                        byte[] lpBuffer,
                                        uint nSize,
                                        out int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
```

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: "If we could even use the PID to get at the full command line, that would probably help." Why can't you? That information is available.

Comment: It looks like the Planet Source Code code won't work for us; upon closer inspection, it appears that just modifies what is displayed in Task Manager, and even then not fully, so anything else such as Perfmon won't be impacted. It's also unknown whether this will work on the newer OSes such as Windows 7.

Comment: I edited above to include a "wmic" command that we can use. If there's nothing better, we might be able to get by with the output of that command.